# Is my transaction to big?

Tags: anchor

I am creating a transaction with these contexts. when I remove an account, (does not matter which one) I am able to make the transaction but whenever I have all of them it fails with the error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Program failed to complete

when i inspect a successful tx with 1 account removed it says its only 690 bytes, so i dont understand why 1 more account makes it fail?

```
#[derive(Accounts)] 
pub struct UserPlay<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub owner: Signer<'info>,
  #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user", owner.key().as_ref()], bump)]
  pub user: Account<'info, User>,
  #[account(seeds = [b"pool", underlying_token_mint.key().as_ref()], bump )]
  pub pool: Account<'info, Pool>, 
  #[account(mut, address = pool.underlying_token_account)] 
  pub pool_underlying_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
  #[account(mut, address = pool.underlying_token_mint)] 
  pub underlying_token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
  #[account(mut,
    associated_token::mint = underlying_token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = owner,
  )]
  pub user_underlying_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
  /// CHECK: 
  #[account(mut)]
  pub creator: AccountInfo<'info>,
  #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = owner,
    associated_token::mint = underlying_token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = creator
  )]
  pub creator_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
  #[account(mut, seeds = [b"program_state"], bump)] 
  pub program_state: Account<'info, ProgramState>,
  #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = owner,
    associated_token::mint = underlying_token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = program_state,
  )]
  pub program_state_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
  pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
  pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: can you share the logs of the failing tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, maybe you've reached your stack limit.

Try boxing your `Account`s if the error is stack related or increasing the [computer cores limit](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction)

Comment: Wow this seems to have worked, need to dig into what this actually does! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your program is consuming more than the maximum limit of Compute Units that it is allowed to consume.  You can increase the number of Compute Units available to your transaction using the ComputeBudget "RequestUnits" instruction.  Note that this will increase the transaction cost of processing the transaction.

The reason that it succeeds when you only process one account instead of more, is probably because the extra compute units used when processing the additional accounts takes the transaction beyond the available Compute Units.

Comment: just to make sure we are on the same page. right now my function is completely empty, no logic in there, I only pass in the context atm. It works if I just remove one account and keep the rest so its not a context with only 1 account! I will try to increase compute units!

Answer (score 0):

you don't seem to have too many accounts, could be, but not so sure.
Are you sure that your IDL is up to date ?

what is your instruction 2? this one ?